# Understanding a proof of the Unique Readability Theorem in FOL ( by Shapiro, Classical Logic).

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

In his proof of the Unique Readability Theorem , Shapiro makes use of a previously proved thesis, namely

***Theorem 5***. Let α,β be nonempty sequences of characters on our alphabet, such that αβ (i.e α followed by β) is a formula. Then α is not a formula.

At some point in his proof ( 5th bullet bellow)  , Shapiro needs to prove that $(\phi_1\&\phi_2)$ cannot be the same formula as $(\phi_3\lor\phi_4)$.

His argument is that $\phi_1$ cannot be a proper part of $\phi_3$ , nor $\phi_3$ of $\phi_1$.

> He justifies this by : Theorem 5.
>
> Could you please tell me in which way Theorem 5 applies here?

Here is the entire proof (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#FeatSynt):

***Theorem 6***. Let θ be any formula of L1K=. If θ is not atomic, then there is one and only one among (2)–(7) that was the last clause applied to construct θ. That is, θ could not be produced by two different clauses. Moreover, no formula produced by clauses (2)–(7) is atomic.

[ Note : the clauses referred to here are the formation rules of the language.]

Proof:

- By Clause (8), either θis atomic or it was produced by one of clauses (2)–(7). Thus, the first symbol in θ must be either a predicate letter, a term, a unary marker, or a left parenthesis.
- If the first symbol in θ is a predicate letter or term, then θ is atomic. In this case, θ was not produced by any of (2)–(7), since all such formulas begin with something other than a predicate letter or term.
- If the first symbol in θ is a negation sign “¬”, then was θ produced by clause (2), and not by any other clause (since the other clauses produce formulas that begin with either a quantifier or a left parenthesis).
- Similarly, if θ begins with a universal quantifier, then it was produced by clause (6), and not by any other clause, and if θ begins with an existential quantifier, then it was produced by clause (7), and not by any other clause.
- The only case left is where θ begins with a left parenthesis. In this case, it must have been produced by one of (3)–(5), and not by any other clause. We only need to rule out the possibility that θ was produced by more than one of (3)–(5). To take an example, suppose that θ was produced by (3) and (4). Then θ is (ψ1&ψ2) and θ is also (ψ3∨ψ4), where ψ1,ψ2,ψ3, and ψ4 are themselves formulas. That is, (ψ1&ψ2) is the very same formula as (ψ3∨ψ4).

> ***By Theorem 5,ψ1 cannot be a proper part of ψ3, nor can ψ3 be a proper part of ψ1.***

So ψ1 must be the same formula as ψ3. But then “&” must be the same symbol as “∨”, and this contradicts the policy that all of the symbols are different. So θ was not produced by both Clause (3) and Clause (4). Similar reasoning takes care of the other combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably clearer to rephrase Theorem 5 as follows:

> If $\gamma$ is a proper initial segment of $\sigma$, we can't have both $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ be formulas.

(Here $\sigma$ is $\alpha\beta$ and $\gamma$ is $\alpha$, in the notation of the original phrasing of Theorem 5.)

As an immediate corollary we get:

> If $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are formulas, then neither is a proper initial segment of the other.

(Otherwise take $\gamma$ to be the shorter and $\sigma$ to be the longer, in the version of Theorem 5 above.)

This is what's being applied to $\psi_1,\psi_3$ in Shapiro's proof.

---

Strictly speaking, "under the hood" there's one more combinatorial fact being applied (below I'll write concatenation as juxtaposition, following Shapiro):

> Suppose $\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2,\gamma,\delta$ are strings of symbols such that $$\alpha\beta_1\gamma=\alpha\beta_2\delta$$ but $$\beta_1\not\prec\beta_2\quad\mbox{and}\quad\beta_2\not\prec\beta_1.$$ Then $\beta_1=\beta_2$.

Above, $\alpha$ is "$($," $\beta_1=\psi_1,\beta_2=\psi_2$, and $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are "$\wedge\psi_2)$" and "$\wedge\psi_4)$" respectively.

Comment: Helpful, thanks!